# how to compare to collections of map in groovy

Tags: groovy, grails, collections, maps

```
def m = [
    [id: 7144, name: "Test załącznika.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7145, name: "Test załącznika 2.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7146, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd..docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7147, name: "Test załącznika 3.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7153, name: "Z.8.DRWS.P.01.F.01.PL.01 Wykaz dokumentów związanych i załączników.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"]
]

def mj = [
    [id: 24930, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy.docx"],
    [id: 24931, name: "Test załącznika nowy.docx"],
    [id: 24932, name: "Test załącznika 3 nowa.docx"],
    [id: 23432, name: "xoxoxoxx.docx"],
    [id: 24933, name: "Test załącznika 2 nowy.docx"]
]

m.each { webcFile ->
    def webcName = webcFile.name
    def webcGroup = webcFile.group

    def webcNameWithoutExtension = webcName.take(webcName.lastIndexOf('.'))

    mj.each { jiraFile ->
        def jiraName = jiraFile.name
        def jiraNameWithoutExtension = jiraName.take(jiraName.lastIndexOf('.'))
        if (jiraNameWithoutExtension.contains(webcNameWithoutExtension) && webcGroup == "3#Gotowe do akceptacji") {

        } else if (!jiraNameWithoutExtension.contains(webcNameWithoutExtension)) {

           println(jiraNameWithoutExtension)


    }
}
}
```

I have to compare two collection of map and print if value from first of map contains value from second or dont.

if statement works fine but else if dont. it should print only xoxoxoxx but prints

```
Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy
xoxoxoxx
Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy
Test załącznika nowy
Test załącznika 3 nowa
xoxoxoxx
Test załącznika nowy
Test załącznika 3 nowa
xoxoxoxx
Test załącznika 2 nowy
Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy
Test załącznika nowy
xoxoxoxx
Test załącznika 2 nowy
Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy
Test załącznika nowy
Test załącznika 3 nowa
xoxoxoxx
Test załącznika 2 nowy
```

from script point of view everything is correct but prints to much. Could you help me a little?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think part of the problem is, that all the file names
from `mj` are all post-fixed with `now[ya]` so there actually are no
duplicated with the rules you put in play here.

Next `each` can not (really) short-circuit, so with two nested `each`
you will pay for some useless work and maybe some wrong output
(assuming, you are not supposed to print possible duplicates).

So I'd suggest to make a look-up first, of what you are looking (note,
that maybe you want to take care about the `novw[ay]` situation there
too).

Then iterate the list, you want to find the dupes in.

```
def m = [
    [id: 7144, name: "Test załącznika.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7145, name: "Test załącznika 2.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7146, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd..docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7147, name: "Test załącznika 3.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7153, name: "Z.8.DRWS.P.01.F.01.PL.01 Wykaz dokumentów związanych i załączników.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
    [id: 7154, name: "xoxoxoxx.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"], // to at least one missing
]

def mj = [
    [id: 24930, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy.docx"],
    [id: 24931, name: "Test załącznika nowy.docx"],
    [id: 24932, name: "Test załącznika 3 nowa.docx"],
    [id: 23432, name: "xoxoxoxx.docx"],
    [id: 24933, name: "Test załącznika 2 nowy.docx"]
]


def stripSuffix = { it.take(it.lastIndexOf('.')) }

// XXX: maybe add now[ay] handling here
def known = mj.stream().map{ stripSuffix it.name }.toSet()

m.each{
    def webcNameWithoutExtension = stripSuffix(it.name)
    if (!known.contains(webcNameWithoutExtension)) {
        println webcNameWithoutExtension
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two things:

1. to turn the `each`-loops into `for`-loops to enable breaking out and
2. switch iterating over `m` and `mj`.

```
def m = [
        [id: 7144, name: "Test załącznika.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
        [id: 7145, name: "Test załącznika 2.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
        [id: 7146, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd..docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
        [id: 7147, name: "Test załącznika 3.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"],
        [id: 7153, name: "Z.8.DRWS.P.01.F.01.PL.01 Wykaz dokumentów związanych i załączników.docx", group: "3#Gotowe do akceptacji"]
]

def mj = [
        [id: 24930, name: "Test integracji dział prawny cd. nowy.docx"],
        [id: 24931, name: "Test załącznika nowy.docx"],
        [id: 24932, name: "Test załącznika 3 nowa.docx"],
        [id: 23432, name: "xoxoxoxx.docx"],
        [id: 24933, name: "Test załącznika 2 nowy.docx"]
]

for (jiraFile in mj) {
    def jiraName = jiraFile.name
    def jiraNameWithoutExtension = jiraName.take(jiraName.lastIndexOf('.'))

    def found = false
    for (webcFile in m) {
        def webcName = webcFile.name
        def webcNameWithoutExtension = webcName.take(webcName.lastIndexOf('.'))
        def webcGroup = webcFile.group
        if (jiraNameWithoutExtension.contains(webcNameWithoutExtension) && webcGroup == "3#Gotowe do akceptacji") {
            found = true
            break
        }
    }
    if(!found)
        print(jiraNameWithoutExtension)
}
```

If you like a more functional approach you could try something like

```
List list = m.findAll { it.group == "3#Gotowe do akceptacji" }
        .collect { map -> getJiraNameWithoutExtension(map) }

mj.collect { map -> getJiraNameWithoutExtension(map) }
    .findAll { name ->  nameNotContainedInList(name, list) }
    .each { println it }


boolean nameNotContainedInList(String name, List<Map> list) {
    list.stream()
        .filter { s -> name.contains(s) }
        .findFirst()
        .isEmpty()
}

String getJiraNameWithoutExtension(Map jiraFile){
    String jiraName = jiraFile.name
    jiraName.take(jiraName.lastIndexOf('.'))
}
```